# Can not access Chrome headless debug

Tags: google-chrome, karma-runner, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I am running a angular 5 unit test on a headless server in Karma and Jasmine. I am using chrome headless to run the tests.

I am not able to access Chrome's debug mode when using with `--remote-debugging-port=9223`.  I tried with `http://35.1.28.84:9223` in my remote chrome url.

I made sure the all interfaces are listening with `host: '0.0.0.0'`. I made sure the port was open also.

How come I am not able to access chrome's debugger remotely?

```
START:
29 03 2018 15:38:05.480:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
29 03 2018 15:38:05.482:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser MyHeadlessChrome with unlimited concurrency
29 03 2018 15:38:05.497:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
29 03 2018 15:38:18.487:INFO [HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket pfKmImL3pGU9ibL7AAAA with id 10485493
```

---

headless-karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    reporters: ['mocha'],
    port: 9876,  // karma web server port
    colors: true,
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    browsers: ['MyHeadlessChrome'],
    customLaunchers: {
      MyHeadlessChrome: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--disable-translate',
          '--disable-extensions',
          '--no-first-run',
          '--disable-background-networking',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9223',
        ]
      }
    },
    autoWatch: false,
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

---

```
one@work:~/github/MCTS.UI  (dh/headless-unittests)
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 64.0.3282.167
one@work:~/github/MCTS.UI  (dh/headless-unittests)
$ google-chrome-stable --version
Google Chrome 64.0.3282.167
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another parameter you need to supply to chrome:

--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0

Use the given address instead of the default loopback for accepting remote debugging connections. Should be used together with --remote-debugging-port. Note that the remote debugging protocol does not perform any authentication, so exposing it too widely can be a security risk.